# custom repartition for color domain

Tags: javascript

I'm using chroma.js to get a color domain from datas. For this I follow the documentation example : https://github.com/gka/chroma.js/blob/master/doc/api.md

> For more advanced techniques you need the actual dataset

```
chroma.scale(['#eee', '#900']).domain(values, 4, 'quantiles');
chroma.scale(['#eee', '#900']).domain(values, 4, 'k-means');
```

The quantiles method split in 4 group so the final repartition looks like 0-25%, 25-50%, 50-75% and 75-100% of values.

Now I would like to custom the repartition method so my group looks like 0-50%, 50-75%, 75-90%, 90-100% of values but I have no idea how to do it...

Anybody know if you can custom the repartition for this function ? (and of course if it's possible, how ?)

Also I'm not really stick to chroma.js, so if someone have a solution using an other librairy or some code, answer is welcome :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to do it with a solution wich is probably not the most beautiful...

If anybody is interest :

```
// split the color domain in 4 for the final uses
var color = chroma.scale(['#eee', '#900']).domain(values, 4, 'quantiles');
// split my values in 100 quartiles
var temp = chroma.scale(['#eee', '#900']).domain(values, 100, 'quantiles');

// replace the value for the color domain from those you want on temp (in my case 0, .50, .75, .90, 1)
color.domain()[0] = temp.domain()[0];
color.domain()[1] = temp.domain()[50];
color.domain()[2] = temp.domain()[75];
color.domain()[3] = temp.domain()[90];
color.domain()[4] = temp.domain()[101];
```

btw I replace color.domain[0] and [4] more for the reading comprehension but they don't change anything because they represent minimum and maximum of the values